# Getting work permit for Spain

Tags: working-visas, spain

I'm from India and I want to know if I marry an European girl (Romanian), will I be able to get the nationality and work permit for Spain as she is living in Spain.

Answer (score 2):

Nationality, not immediately.  Right to live and work in Spain, yes, unless the authorities determine that you entered into the relationship for the purpose of being able to live and work in Spain.

After living in Spain for some time, you will generally become eligible for naturalization, though there can be additional requirements.

After living in Spain for five years, you will generally acquire a right of permanent residence.

Comment: Naturalization also requires five years unless you are a citizen of another Spanish-speaking country.

Comment: @WGroleau, no, ten years (with a few exceptions).

Comment: Ten years is correct; thanks, @PeterTaylor.  And I even read that on a Spanish government website.  Senior moment.  :-)

Comment: @wgroleau Not exactly a Spanish speaking country but countries with "special ties". That includes Portugal, Brazil, Philippines and Sephardite jews regardles of nationality.

Comment: Don't forget that in Spain everything is too slow. Once you request your nationality you might need to wait another 1,5 year for being approved.